# Installing Ghost CMS on a shared hosting

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal, shared-hosting, ghost-blog

I am trying to install **Ghost CMS** in a subdomain of my shared server but can't get to run the install locally commnad in my subdomain folder. The command I am using is this `ghost install local`.

To be able to run node.js in my shared server in I speciefic folder the cpanel has something called **"Setup Node.js App"**  here is where I start to be confused. Then I install it, then in the terminal, I go to a  `source....` link they give me after the node installation.

After that, I run de node and npm version check, and they are working ok.

I install ghost globally `npm install ghost-cli@latest -g` without any problem, but after that, I can not run the `ghost install local`

Maybe I am doing all wrong and there is a better way to install Ghost in my server.

Tech Support said that the server meets all the requirements.

The server from Namecheap Stellar Plan, Is a Linux shared server and supports SSH and some of the major technologies, included Node.js But I can't make this to work. Locally on my computer it was easy and fast. But **on the server** (which is the point) **I don't know what steps to follow**.

I'll be grateful about your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little late to the party, but you have to add the path of the ghost binary to the PATH environment variable. This path is stated when you install ghost-cli, you simply have have to insert the last `lib/` bit in the path.

**Development:**

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/<your-home>/nodevenv/<your-node-js-ghost-app>/10/lib/bin/"
```

**Production:**

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/<your-home>/<your-node-js-ghost-app>/10/lib/bin/"
```

Then you have to make sure the directory is empty. It will likely not be, then rm -rf everything in it.

Then you will be able to perform your command:

```
$ ghost install local
```

and it should run without error.

Comment: Thanks @Pianographe I'll try this, and come back with news. Nice day

Comment: Sorry dude, didn't had look solving it

Comment: Hello,

Can you please paste (anonymized) the path that gets printed once you install ghost-cli?
The export command needs to fit it for the command to work.
The whole idea being that ghost is not part of the PATH, you can workaround the issue calling "ghost" using its full absolute path ;-)

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your help. Good news is, I just make it work with your advice, the ghost installer is running as expected, but crashing at the end due to an incompatible  `Message: Command failed: yarn install --no-emoji --no-progress` an some other incompatible packages, for example: `info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.` I am starting to guess if I should abandon the idea of having the ghost as blog.